# Android data handling

Tags: android, image, web-services, camera

I'm creating an app where users can upload data and pictures, which are stored in my server, and those data can be accessed by other users.

1. How do I send/receive data and pics to/from my server
2. I am planning to provide camera in the app, if so how do I manage the size of pics for easy accessing both ways

Answer (score 1):

you should be more specific, about the technology you plan to use for the server side.  Whatever you choose, Try with [JSON](http://www.json.org/) for easy protocol on your data transfer from server to device, search for what frame work to use for the android part

here an example with , 
[REST](http://www.androidsnippets.com/retrieve-json-from-a-rest-web-service)

Answer (score 0):

[Android ION library](https://github.com/koush/ion) can help with sending images in both directions.

If you plan to use Camera Intent, you will have no control over the images you get back, so you will need to resize them on your side. If you use the Camera API (a.k.a. custom camera) in your app, you can choose any picture size supported by your device.